# I want to clear DNS cache

Tags: caching, dns

I have a problem with clearing DNS Cache.
When we publish any post on our website it was getting published in the Dailyhunt news portal.
But for the past few days, our posts are not getting posted in Dailyhunt. When we ask their technical team they told us to clear the DNS cache on regular basis. Because of cache, our posts are not getting published in Daily Hunt.

So how to clear the DNS cache on regular basis?

Answer (score 0):

The response you received seems a little bit superficial. I can't find an immediate correlation between the DNS cache and your posts not being published on a portal. Especially if you are publishing content, and not provisioning new hosts.

If you need to clear the DNS cache locally you can follow these instructions on [how to flush the DNS cache on various operating systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/16299/how-do-i-flush-the-dns-cache-on-win-mac-linux-computers). However, while these commands will produce the expected outcome on your system, I do not expect them to solve your problem.

From what I read, I think the cache they referred to was not the DNS cache, but the site cache. It is possible your site has a caching mechanism that doesn't immediately publish new content. If you use a CMS or publishing platform, such as Wordpress, check your settings and plugins. It is very plausible that you have a setting that caches your published pages for a period of time to increase performance.